# Generate an access token with GoogleAuth() and pass it to a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I'm using Google Translate's new [Romanization service](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/romanize-text), which is in beta preview, from my Angular front end. I got it all working but my code could be cleaner!

Angular calls my Cloud Function for Firebase `Call_Google_Auth` and passes in a phrase and a language. `Call_Google_Auth` generates [two bearer tokens](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types): an access token and an ID token. I put the access token into the `request.data` object along with the phrase and language. `Call_Google_Auth` then runs the `authRequest()` function which uses the ID token to call the second Cloud Function, `Call_Google_Romanize_HTTP`. The second function throws away the ID token and uses the access token in `request.data.token` to call Google Translate Romanization.

Can I get rid of the code that generates the ID token and just generate the access token?

Here's my code for the two functions:

```js
export const Call_Google_Auth = onCall(async (request) => {
  const targetAudience = 'https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/Call_Google_Romanize_HTTP';
  const url = targetAudience;

  const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();

  const token = await new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
  }).getAccessToken();
  request.data.token = token;

  async function authRequest() {
    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
    const res = await client.request( {
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(request.data),
    })
    console.info(res.body);
  };
   
  authRequest().catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
}); // end Call_Google_Auth

export const Call_Google_Romanize_HTTP = onRequest(async (request: any, response: any) => {
    const options = {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + request.body.token, // Bearer access token, works
        // "Authorization": request.rawHeaders[11], // Bearer ID token, doesn't work
        "x-goog-user-project": "my-project",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      },
      json: {
        "source_language_code": request.body.source_language_code,
        "contents": request.body.contents,
      }
    };

    response = await got.post("https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/my-project/locations/us-central1:romanizeText", options).json();
    logger.log(response.romanizations);
    return response.romanizations;

}); // end Call_Google_Romanize_HTTP
```

I want to change this line in my Cloud Function `Call_Google_Auth`:

```js
const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience); // generates ID token
```

into something like this:

```js
const client = await auth.getAccessToken("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"); // generates access token
```

This code throws an error `client.request is not a function`.

If you're wondering why I don't put `getAccessToken()` in the second Cloud Function `Call_Google_Romanize_HTTP` and call this function directly from Angular, at first I was getting CORS errors. I fixed that and now I'm getting the error `Response code 400 (Bad Request)`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the above code is as simple as it can be. Google has five or six types of tokens. The ID token is needed to call the second Cloud Function from the first Cloud Function and avoid a CORS error. The access token is needed for the second Cloud Function to call the Google Translate API. It's not possible to do both with a single token.